# Lambda as an argument in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need to create a method which can be called so

```
list_of_hash_values = MyModel.values_and_links :title, "some_query_param", lambda{|id| url_for :controller => :my_model, :action => :show, :id=> id }
```

It gets 3 arguments: field name (as a symbol), query parameter and lambda with one parameter. And it returns hash of values and their urls. Lambda return some string value (in this case it is ulr of a model instance).

I tried to do:

```
class MyModel

 def values_and_links(title, query_param, lambda_exp)

   instance_values = MyModel.order(:title).where("#{title} = ?", "%#{query_param}%")
   instance_values.each do |item|
      {:hash_key1 => item.send(title), :hash_key2 => lambda_exp.call(title)} 
   end

 end
end
```

It's wrong, not working.

I hope you understand what I need to accomplish. How can I do it? How can I implement method `values_and_links`?

Comment: 1) It should be `def self.values_and_links` to be called as a classmethod. 2) In Ruby when a method takes only a lambda is idiomatic to use a real block for that argument, not a lambda/proc.

Comment: What specifically is not working? It looks like you aren't accumulating the return values, for one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a block instead:

```
class MyModel
 def values_and_links(title, query_param)
   instance_values = MyModel.order(:title).where("#{title} = ?", "%#{query_param}%")
   instance_values.each do |item|
      {:hash_key1 => item.send(title), :hash_key2 => yield(title)} 
   end
 end
end
```

then, you can call your method like this:

```
list_of_hash_values = MyModel.values_and_links :title, "some_query_param" do |id|
  url_for :controller => :my_model, :action => :show, :id=> id
end
```

or, for 'short':

```
list_of_hash_values = MyModel.values_and_links :title, "some_query_param" {|id| url_for :controller => :my_model, :action => :show, :id=> id}
```

Comment: Now it's pretty clear for me that it's possible to use `block` here (because I can see the sources). But how another person (client) is going to know that they can use block in `values_and_links`? Probably it's better to add a parameter `&block`? Even more, if they know that they can use `block`, how are they going to know how many parameter they can pass to it (to block)?

Comment: I often use `&block` although invoking it with yield so i don't forget that the method takes a block. The answer to your second question perhaps simply is documentation. If you want many people to use your code, you should have a good documentation anyway. If yo have never looked into this, check out http://yardoc.org . I love it.

Comment: Oh, and how would the user know how many parameters the lambda should take?